# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skfeature'

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, statistics

I am unable to import fisher score from `skfeature.function.similiarity_based`.

Is there a problem in my code below?

```py
from skfeature.function.similarity_based import fisher_score
ranks = fisher_score(X,Y)
feature_importance = pd.Series(ranks,df.columns[0:len(df.columns) - 1])
feature_importance.plot(kind = 'barh', color = 'magenta')
plt.show()
```

I'm working on Kaggle notebook not locally.

I've tried installing it using pip commands and have tried to look for other alternatives but nothing seems to work.

Comment: How did you install it? According to github repo, it seems like you need to install from source https://github.com/jundongl/scikit-feature not via pip.

Comment: I was trying to install incorrect module, I needed to install 'skfeature-chappers' while I was installing 'skfeature'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a third-party library not associated with scikit-learn.

Someone uploaded a version to PyPi ([PyPi](https://github.com/charliec443/scikit-feature), [GitHub](https://github.com/charliec443/scikit-feature)):

```
pip install skfeature-chappers
```

Or the original should be possible to install directly [from GitHub](https://github.com/jundongl/scikit-feature) with:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/jundongl/scikit-feature.git
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response... installing 'skfeature-chappers' worked for me.